# Laravel - How to Import Vue Component to Another Component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new in **Vue.js**. I want to understand on using `component`. I tried to import my component to another component but it failed. I am using `Laravel 5.8`. Below are the error that I received.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './components/modalAlert.vue

Below are my codes.

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('form-to-do', require('./components/formToDo.vue').default);
Vue.component('modal-alert', require('./components/modalAlert.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**formToDo.Vue**

```
<template>
// form 

<modal-alert></modal-alert>
</template>

<script>
import modalAlert from './components/modalAlert.vue';

export default {
    components: {
       'modal-alert': modalAlert 
    },

    data() {
        return {
            setErrors: [],
            tasks: [],
            task: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                completed: '',
                date_completed: ''
            },
            result: '',
            input: {
                name: ''
            }
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

**modalAlert.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Test  
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['id'],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your components are probably in the same folder. In your component formToDo.vue:
Change this:

```
import modalAlert from './components/modalAlert.vue';
```

To this:

```
import modalAlert from './modalAlert.vue';
```

To solve the other issue, as @ambianBeing suggested, your component formToDo.vue must have root element to be able to add child component inside it.

```
<template>
<div> <!-- this is the root -->
    <modal-alert></modal-alert>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: after edit as you suggest. Now the error is ```Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.```

Comment: That's other problem. Show us the code of modalAlert.vue component.

Comment: I updated my question for the ```modalAlert.vue``` component on my question.

Comment: @Khairul The `formToDo.Vue` should have root element (div etc.) if it does not and then should compose (template,components etc). `<template><div id="formToDoContainer"><modal-alert></modal-alert></div></template>`